# How to update Object key value conditionally using spread operator?

Tags: javascript

I need to update Existing object conditionally using spread operator.
Below my code

```
      const resetPerson: any = {...person, name: '', age: '', location && location : '' };
```

if location key exist in person object then only clear location else no need to add location property.

How can I do that.

Comment: `const resetPerson: any = location ? { ...person, name: '', age: '', location : '' }  : { ...person, name: '', age: '' } ;`

Comment: @Nick looks good Thanks. Is there any way to optimize code.

Comment: @Nagasai What do you want to optimize?

Comment: @jabaa I don't want to repeat keys `const resetPerson: any = { ...person, name: '', age: '' }; person.location && {....resetPerson, location: ''}` kind of this example

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally add an object property like this:

```
const resetPerson: any = {
  ...person,
  name: '',
  age: '',
  ...('location' in person && { location: '' })
};
```